# Какое событие необходимо сделать?

Tags: html, jquery

Есть скрипт который контролирует 2 поля input, если в первом поле введено значение больше 12 символов, то второе поле блокируется, но когда перезагружаю страницу, данные в полях остаются, но второе поле не заблокировано. Как можно сделать так, чтобы при перезагрузки проверялась длина первого поля и сразу второе поле становилось disabled, смог сделать только при наведении, нажатия.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Фишка в том, чтобы искусственно вызвать событие, выполняющее проверку длины значения первого поля, при загрузке страницы:

```
$('#field1').on('keyup', function() {
    $('#field2').prop('disabled', this.value.length > 12);
}).trigger('keyup');  // <-- вот так
```

**ДЕМО:** http://jsfiddle.net/qy2x21e4/